# SOLVED Pi 400 Bullseye 11 digital clock format from 24-hour to 12 hour

Tags: system-clock

Currently:
Digital Clock
Format  %R
Tool tip format %A %x

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
%R  24 hr     %r   12 hr.

Comment: what's  your  question?

Comment: the question is in the subject line.  How to change digital clock to 12 hour clock.  Since then, I found the anwer.  Change %R to %r..  I do sincerely thank you for the reply.

Comment: your post does not contain the words `How to change` ... it contains no question at all

Comment: if you like, you can write the answer in the `Your Answer` section below, so that others can benefit ... then you can accept your own answer

Comment: The keyword in the subject FROM clarifies adequately but I will try to keep you in mind in the future.
Thank you for clarifying the Your Answer issue.  Nowhere is that explained that I can find.  I will try to keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ... so here is the answer .... which I found out with a Goog search.

Change R to r.